# Incomplete or not the desirable output

Tags: android

The code is about making a contact manager application Everything is working  but when the contact is added, it is not being shown in the list when we click the list tab.

Code:

```
package com.example.tanmay.myapplication2;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText nameTxt,phoneTxt,emailTxt,addressTxt;
List<Contact> Contacts=new ArrayList<Contact>();
ListView contactListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    phoneTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    emailTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    addressTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("creator");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabCreator);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("creator");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("List");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


    final Button addBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addContact(nameTxt.getText().toString(),phoneTxt.getText().toString(),emailTxt.getText().toString(),addressTxt.getText().toString());
            populateList();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nameTxt.getText().toString() +"has been added to your contacts!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    nameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            addBtn.setEnabled(!nameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

private void populateList(){
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ContactListAdapter();
    contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addContact(String name,String phone,String email,String address){
    Contacts.add(new Contact(name,phone,email,address));

}

private class ContactListAdapter extends com.example.tanmay.myapplication2.ContactListAdapter {
    public ContactListAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.listview_item, Contacts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent){
        if(view==null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item,parent,false);

        Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

        TextView name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        name.setText(currentContact.getName());
        TextView phone=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
        TextView email=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
        TextView address=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
        address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());

        return view;
    }



    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must notify your adapter that your dataset has been updated by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding your Contact POJO your your ArrayList.

To do so you will need to retain a reference of your adapter

Do not call `populateList()` after calling `addContact()` in your `onClick()` callback as it will reset completely your list which is something you don't want.

Here is what you need :

```
private ContactListAdapter mAdapter;

private void populateList() {
    mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter();
    contactListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void addContact(String name,String phone,String email,String address) {
    Contacts.add(new Contact(name,phone,email,address));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

final Button addBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addContact(nameTxt.getText().toString(),phoneTxt.getText().toString(),emailTxt.getText().toString(),addressTxt.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nameTxt.getText().toString() +"has been added to your contacts!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: how do i notify my adapter that my dataset has been updated by calling notifyDataSetChanged() (calling it where) and how do i add  Contact to ArrayList

Comment: its showing error that private could not be used as private ContactListAdapter mAdapter and its showing illegal start expression error

Comment: forget the above comments

Comment: its running but it stops when I click on addcontacts button anddisplays message myapplication2 stops error

Comment: If you get a NPE it's most likely because you never set your adapter by calling populateList() in the onCreate(). Hence you try to call notifyDataSetChanged on a null reference.

Comment: I did called populateList() in the onCreate().